# Performance improvement on vb.net code

Tags: performance, memory-management, vb.net

I need to write 5 crores records with 72 columns into text file, the file size is growing as 9.7gb .

I need to check each and every columm length need to format as according to the length as defined in XML file.

Reading records from oracle one by one and checking the format and writing into text file.

To write 5 crores records it is taking more than 24 hours. How can I increase the performance in the below code?

```
Dim valString As String = Nothing
        Dim valName As String = Nothing
        Dim valLength As String = Nothing
        Dim valDataType As String = Nothing
        Dim validationsArray As ArrayList = GetValidations(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\ReportFormat.xml")
        Console.WriteLine("passed xml")
        Dim k As Integer = 1


        Try
            Console.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Now())
            Dim selectSql As String = "select * from table where
            " record_date >= To_Date('01-01-2014','DD-MM-YYYY') and record_date <= To_Date('31-12-2014','DD-MM-YYYY')"
            Dim dataTable As New DataTable
            Dim oracleAccess As New OracleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("OracleConnection"))
            Dim cmd As New OracleCommand()
            cmd.Connection = oracleAccess
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.CommandText = selectSql
            oracleAccess.Open()
            Dim Tablecolumns As New DataTable()
            Using oracleAccess
                Using writer = New StreamWriter(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\FileName.txt")
                    Using odr As OracleDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                        Dim sbHeaderData As New StringBuilder
                        For i As Integer = 0 To odr.FieldCount - 1
                            sbHeaderData.Append(odr.GetName(i))
                            sbHeaderData.Append("|")
                        Next
                        writer.WriteLine(sbHeaderData)
                        While odr.Read()
                            Dim sbColumnData As New StringBuilder
                            Dim values(odr.FieldCount - 1) As Object
                            Dim fieldCount As Integer = odr.GetValues(values)
                            For i As Integer = 0 To fieldCount - 1
                                Dim vals As Array = validationsArray(i).ToString.ToUpper.Split("|")
                                valName = vals(0).trim
                                valDataType = vals(1).trim
                                valLength = vals(2).trim

                                Select Case valDataType
                                    Case "VARCHAR2"
                                        If values(i).ToString().Length = valLength Then
                                            sbColumnData.Append(values(i).ToString())
                                            'sbColumnData.Append("|")
                                        ElseIf values(i).ToString().Length > valLength Then
                                            sbColumnData.Append(values(i).ToString().Substring(0, valLength))
                                            'sbColumnData.Append("|")
                                        Else
                                            sbColumnData.Append(values(i).ToString().PadRight(valLength))
                                            'sbColumnData.Append("|")
                                        End If
                                    Case "NUMERIC"
                                        valLength = valLength.Substring(0, valLength.IndexOf(","))
                                        If values(i).ToString().Length = valLength Then
                                            sbColumnData.Append(values(i).ToString())
                                            'sbColumnData.Append("|")
                                        Else
                                            sbColumnData.Append(values(i).ToString().PadLeft(valLength, "0"c))
                                            'sbColumnData.Append("|")
                                        End If
                                        'sbColumnData.Append((values(i).ToString()))
                                End Select
                            Next
                            writer.WriteLine(sbColumnData)

                            k = k + 1
                            Console.WriteLine(k)
                        End While
                    End Using
                    writer.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Now())
                End Using
            End Using

            Console.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Now())
            'Dim Adpt As New OracleDataAdapter(selectSql, oracleAccess)
            'Adpt.Fill(dataTable)
            Return Tablecolumns
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Now())
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " & ex.Message)
            Console.ReadLine()
            Return Nothing
        End Try
```

Comment: Writing to the console is very slow. If odr contains a lot of rows, you might see improvement by removing the console.writeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, what is happening here

```
Select Case valDataType
    Case "VARCHAR2"
        If values(i).ToString().Length = valLength Then
            sbColumnData.Append(values(i).ToString())
            'sbColumnData.Append("|")
        ElseIf values(i).ToString().Length > valLength Then
            sbColumnData.Append(values(i).ToString().Substring(0, valLength))
            'sbColumnData.Append("|")
        Else
            sbColumnData.Append(values(i).ToString().PadRight(valLength))
            'sbColumnData.Append("|")
        End If
    Case "NUMERIC"
        valLength = valLength.Substring(0, valLength.IndexOf(","))
        If values(i).ToString().Length = valLength Then
            sbColumnData.Append(values(i).ToString())
            'sbColumnData.Append("|")
        Else
            sbColumnData.Append(values(i).ToString().PadLeft(valLength, "0"c))
            'sbColumnData.Append("|")
        End If
        'sbColumnData.Append((values(i).ToString()))
End Select
```

if `values(i).ToString().Length` is < `valLength` ? You are calling 3 times `.ToString()` on the object. A much faster and better way would be to just do it once like so

```
Dim currentValue As String = values(i).ToString()
Select Case valDataType
    Case "VARCHAR2"
        If vcurrentValue.Length = valLength Then
            sbColumnData.Append(currentValue)
        ElseIf currentValue.Length > valLength Then
            sbColumnData.Append(currentValue.Substring(0, valLength))
        Else
            sbColumnData.Append(currentValue.PadRight(valLength))
        End If

    Case "NUMERIC"
        valLength = valLength.Substring(0, valLength.IndexOf(","))
        If currentValue.Length = valLength Then
            sbColumnData.Append(currentValue)
        Else
            sbColumnData.Append(currentValue.PadLeft(valLength, "0"c))
        End If

End Select
```

---

I don't like this

> ```
> Dim vals As Array = validationsArray(i).ToString.ToUpper.Split("|")
> valName = vals(0).trim
> valDataType = vals(1).trim
> valLength = vals(2).trim
> ```

for a couple of reasons. First you are creating a string array out of this `ArrayList` (however this is created) and then store it in an `Array` so casting it to an object to cast it again to a `String` on the next lines.

But then you use the valLength `String`'s to compare with `Length` which is an `Integer`.

The `valName` variable is never used, so you can just remove it along with the commented code. Code which isn't used or is commented is just dead code which should be removed to increase readability.

Another thing bothering me is the use of abbreviations for variables names. You won't gain any performancy increase by doing so, but you loose a lot of readability.

```
Dim validationValues As String() = validationsArray(i).ToString.ToUpper.Split("|")
Dim valueDataType As String = validationValues(1).Trim()
Dim valueLength As String = validationValues(1).Trim() 
Dim currentValue As String = values(i).ToString()

Select Case valDataType
    Case "VARCHAR2"

        Dim length As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(valueLength)

        If vcurrentValue.Length = length Then
            sbColumnData.Append(currentValue)
        ElseIf currentValue.Length > length Then
            sbColumnData.Append(currentValue.Substring(0, length))
        Else
            sbColumnData.Append(currentValue.PadRight(length))
        End If

    Case "NUMERIC"

        Dim length As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(valueLength.Substring(0, valueLength.IndexOf(",")))

        If currentValue.Length = length Then
            sbColumnData.Append(currentValue)
        Else
            sbColumnData.Append(currentValue.PadLeft(length, "0"c))
        End If

End Select
```

Another thing which is slowing down the performance is that you do this

> ```
> Dim vals As Array = validationsArray(i).ToString.ToUpper.Split("|")
> valName = vals(0).trim
> valDataType = vals(1).trim
> valLength = vals(2).trim
> ```

for each datarow **and** each column. You should store these values once an reuse the values for each other datarow.

---

> ```
> k = k + 1
> Console.WriteLine(k)
> ```

This doesn't serve any real purpose but will slow down your code. Get rid of it.

---

You are using `using` statements to enclose objects which implements `IDisposable` which is good, but why don't you be consistent ? The `OracleCommand` also implements `IDisposable` but there is no using.

---

> ```
> Dim Tablecolumns As New DataTable()
> ```

this isn't used anywhere except for the return value of the method. You can simply change it to a `Sub` and remove this variable.

---

Doing a `select * from table where...` won't help any in the meaning of increasing performance. You only need columns which are either `VARCHAR2` or `NUMERIC` so you should only add these columns to your select query which meets this requirement. There is for instance no use for any `Date` field like `record_date`. You don't need to retrieve this column to restrict the query to the value of it.

Comment: Heslacher the code is running very fast and it came to very less time i.e, 2days to 2 hrs . Thank you very much for quick help